# How to seperate a 2d mask array into the individual segments within it?

Tags: python, arrays, image-segmentation

## Context

Im trying to take an array which consists of 1s and 0s in random locations and then seperate clusters of 1s within this array and label them seperately. I think it is best explained with an example.

[On the left I have an example input and on the right is the example output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YOwI.png)

## My solution

To do this I wrote a recursive function which essentially fills in clusters and I essentially loop through the input array and then if I find one I will call this function to fill in that cluster. I have included python code below.

```
def search(i,j,dmask,lbls,lbl):

lbls[i,j] = lbl
if (i-1 < dmask.shape[0]) & (j-1 < dmask.shape[1]) & (i-1 >= 0) & (j-1 >= 0):
    if  (dmask[i-1,j-1] == 1) & (lbls[i-1,j-1] == 0):
        search(i-1,j-1,dmask,lbls,lbl)

if (i-1 < dmask.shape[0]) & (j < dmask.shape[1]) & (i-1 >= 0) & (j >= 0):
    if (dmask[i-1,j] == 1) & (lbls[i-1,j] == 0) :
        search(i-1,j,dmask,lbls,lbl)

if (i-1 < dmask.shape[0]) & (j+1 < dmask.shape[1]) & (i-1 >= 0 ) & ( j+1 >= 0 ):
    if ( dmask[i-1,j+1] == 1 ) & ( lbls[i-1,j+1] == 0):
        search(i-1,j+1,dmask,lbls,lbl)

if (i < dmask.shape[0]) & (j-1 < dmask.shape[1]) & (i >= 0 ) & ( j - 1 >= 0 ):
    if (dmask[i,j-1] == 1 ) & ( lbls[i,j-1] == 0 ):
        search(i,j-1,dmask,lbls,lbl)    
        
if (i < dmask.shape[0]) & (j+1 < dmask.shape[1]) & (i >= 0 ) & ( j+1 >= 0 ):
    if (dmask[i,j+1] == 1 ) & ( lbls[i,j+1] == 0):
        search(i,j+1,dmask,lbls,lbl)
        
if (i+1 < dmask.shape[0]) & (j-1 < dmask.shape[1]) & (i+1 >= 0 ) & ( j-1 >= 0 ):
    if ( dmask[i+1,j-1] == 1 ) & ( lbls[i+1,j-1] == 0): 
        search(i+1,j-1,dmask,lbls,lbl)
        
if (i+1 < dmask.shape[0]) & (j < dmask.shape[1]) & (i+1 >= 0 ) & ( j >= 0 ):
    if ( dmask[i+1,j] == 1 ) & ( lbls[i+1,j] == 0):
        search(i+1,j,dmask,lbls,lbl)
        
if (i+1 < dmask.shape[0]) & (j+1 < dmask.shape[1]) & (i+1 >= 0 ) & ( j+1 >= 0 ):
    if (dmask[i+1,j+1] == 1 ) & ( lbls[i+1,j+1] == 0):
        search(i+1,j+1,dmask,lbls,lbl)
return dmask,lbls

Initiliazing the label

lbl = 1;

Input array

a = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],[1,1,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,0,1,1]])

Intializing the output array

b = np.zeros(np.shape(a),int)

Iterating through the array and calling the recursive function if a 1 is located

for i in np.arange(a.shape[0]):
    for j in np.arange(a.shape[1]):
        if (a[i,j] == 1) & (b[i,j] == 0):
            [c,d] = search(i,j,a,b,lbl)
            lbl += 1;
```

## The problem

This solutions works for small input arrays, for example the picture I have included. However I need it to work on a much larger array which has much larger clusters. This results in my kernel restarting automatically when i run the code. I believe this is because it is hitting the recursion limit although I have tried increasing the recursion limit using the sys.setrecursionlimit() function.

Does anyone have any advice on how I can bypass this issue. I DON'T need to provide my own solution to this problem. If there is a library that does this very easily then that would be great.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an old classical subject in computer vision.
In image the "cluster of 1s" is called **blob** or **connected component** and the act of identify them is called **blob extraction** or **labeling**.

Use opencv library (`pip install opencv-python`) to find for you all blobs, and filter them out as you wish.
In opencv look at `connectedComponentsWithStats` or `findContours` or `SimpleBlobDetector`.
You can also search in google for "opencv blob detection" or "opencv connected components".

Comment: Thanks so much for the assistance, I didn't realise that blob extraction was what I was after. The "connectedComponentsWithStats" command from the opencv library seems to do exactly what I need plus more!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cv2.findContours()` to grab the contours of all the blobs and then filter using contour area with `cv2.contourArea()`

```py
import numpy as np 
import cv2
import random

def get_random_color():
    r = random.randint(0,255)
    g = random.randint(0,255)
    b = random.randint(0,255)
    
    return (int(r), int(g), int(b))

image = cv2.imread('/your/img/path.bmp')
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
threshold_area = 0.5
for c in cnts:
    rgb = get_random_color()
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > threshold_area:
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, tuple(rgb), -1)

cv2.imwrite('/result/img/path.bmp', mask)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]